# Wordpress Home Page

Tags: homepage

I'm setting up Wordpress version 3.8.1 on my website.  It's installed at the domain root (`http://www.mywebsite.com/[wordpress installation]`).  I added a "Home" page.  Afterward when editing the menu settings I noticed that there were two entries for Home.  Upon further investigation I discovered that the Home page I made had a permalink of `http://www.mywebsite.com/home/`.  So, now I have two questions:

1. How do I fix the permalink for my Home page, so that it is `http://www.mywebsite.com/`?
2. Since I'm only able to get at one of the Home pages shown in the menu settings, how do I get rid of the extra Home page, so that I have only one editable Home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go to `WP-Admin > Settings > Reading > Front page displays > A static page (select below) > Front Page` and select your `Home`.

Second, go to `Appearance > Menus`, remove the duplicated `Home` entry and ensure the link of the other is pointed to `http://www.yourwebsite.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the original homepage or index.html resting at the root directory.

And I believe just move the directory of the wordpress installation just to the main root of the servers directory at:

`/`